# Add url to direct logout link?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I need help with this;

I added this line of PHP code in a menu option using sourcerer.

```
<li style="list-style:none;">
    <?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser(); {
        $userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
        echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_users&view=login&layout=logout' . $userToken . '=1;" >Logout ' .'</a>';
    }
    ?>
</li>
```

Now, I need to redirect to a page once the user clicks this menu link.

I would like to redirect the user to the home page.

Now, when I use this link to logout it just goes to an empty page.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without Sourcerer. A direct logout link is core behaviour of Joomla.

- Create a menu item of the type users > logout.
- Set the redirect option to point to your homepage, or wherever you want it to go.
- If you need to create a logout link which isn't part of a menu, then just use the link `<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?Itemid=111"); ?>">LOGOUT</a>` replacing 111 with the id of your logout menu item.
- In a WYSIWYG area, you should be able to just use `<a href="index.php?Itemid=111">LOGOUT</a>`, as links here should be automatically passed through JRoute without the need for PHP extensions.

I'd strongly advise never to use Sourcerer.  It's a hack tool which encourages terrible development practise.  Joomla has a strong framework using components and modules which helps keep content, database and styles separate and easy-to-maintain, and which other developers can easily follow.  Sourcerer makes maintenance of a site almost impossible.  It's bad enough mixing styles and content in a single database cell, let alone styles, server-side code and content.

Comment: Thanks a lot man I will be giving it a try. I will also look into the advice you gave. Will create the menu link and add the numbers on the end of the URL. Thanks again!\